# Loading concrete child types based on abstract parent properties via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

The project I've just moved to has an abstract class `Product` which it was chosen to do this way since there are 4 children types that are considered a product and share a fair amount of commonality (the reason over composition).  `Product` has a `ProductType` enum associated with it.  I need to make some static functionality associated with `Product` like `GetAllProducts()`.

There lies my issue since the `Product` table only has the commonality data, where as I need each `ProductType` to hit and select it's own tables information joined with the `Product` table.

The backend to the model is using the EntityFramework + OData, a technology I'm not familiar with.

What's considered the appropriate way to get each child type's fully loaded data (+ all the commonality related to it too) from the database even though I won't know what that child type is until I've selected it from my linq query? And, let's say I have that data returned, does it make sense to switch on `ProductType` to create the actual child types via their own constructors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool part about EF + WCF Data Services (OData is the protocol, WCF DS is a Microsoft implementation of OData) is that a lot of this is magic. You don't need any special joins or other magic.

Here's some code to get you started: (I'll walk through it below, I promise.)

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Scratch.Web
{
    // 4
    [ServiceBehavior(IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    // 1
    public class ScratchService : DataService<ScratchContext>
    {
        static ScratchService()
        {
            // 2
            Database.SetInitializer(new ScratchContextInitializer());
        }

        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // 3
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;
            // 4
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        }
    }

    public class ScratchContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ScratchContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ScratchContext context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
            // 5
            context.Products.Add(new DiscontinuedProduct
                                     {
                                         Name = "DP1",
                                         DiscontinuedAt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
                                     });
            context.Products.Add(new DiscountedProduct
                                     {
                                         Name = "DP1",
                                         Discount = 3.14
                                     });
        }
    }
    // 6
    public class ScratchContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
    // 7
    public abstract class Product
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    // 7
    public class DiscountedProduct : Product
    {
        public double Discount { get; set; }
    }
    // 7
    public class DiscontinuedProduct : Product
    {
        public DateTime DiscontinuedAt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Quick walkthrough:

- 1: The `ScratchService` is the WCF Data Service in this case. It inherits from `DataService<T>` and supplies a `DbContext` (an EF concept) as the generic type.
- 2: We use the static constructor to set a database initializer since I modify this code all the time.
- 3: We make Entity Sets and Service Ops visible to service consumers (a `*/All` approach is NOT recommended.)
- 4: We enable debugging (always useful)
- 5: We seed the database to get some data into it
- 6: We create a `DbContext` for EF and expose the abstract class `Product` as a `DbSet`. (Note that you'll need WCF DS 5 or greater to work with `DbContext`; WCF DS 5.0.1 [or 5.1.0-rc1 if you're brave] and EF 4.3.1 play great together.)
- 7: We create a class structure with an abstract class at the root and two derived classes.

Note that when EF is in play, you follow its rules:
 - I could have had `ProductId` without a `DataServiceKey` attribute and EF would make that the key for the entity, which WCF DS will respect
 - TPT/TPH/TPC is all per EF settings
 - If you want to do code first from the database (which it sounds like you probably do), there's a [download that will help you with that](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d)

Answer (score 1):

```
            var result=(
                        from product in context.Products
                        join child1 in context.Child1s
                        on product.ID equals child1.ProductID
                        join child2 in context.Child2s
                        on product.ID equals child2.ProductID
                        join child3 in context.Child3s
                        on product.ID equals child3.ProductID
                        join child4 in context.Child4s
                        on product.ID equals child4.ProductID
                        where product.ID<1000
                        select new {

                                        AnonTypeProduct=product,
                                        AnonTypeChild1=child1,
                                        AnonTypeChild2=child2,
                                        AnonTypeChild3=child3,
                                        AnonTypeChild4=child4,

                        }).ToList();
        IEnumerable<Child1> ch1list=new IEnumerable<Child1>();
        IEnumerable<Child2> ch2list =new IEnumerable<Child2>();
        IEnumerable<Child3> ch3list=new IEnumerable<Child3>();
        IEnumerable<Child4> ch4list=new IEnumerable<Child4>();
        foreach(var result in results)
        {
            Child1 ch1=new Child1();
            ch1=result.AnonTypeChild1;
            ch1.Product=AnonTypeProduct;
            Child2 ch2=new Child2();
            ch2=result.AnonTypeChild2;
            ch2.Product=AnonTypeProduct;
            Child3 ch3=new Child3();
            ch3=result.AnonTypeChild3;
            ch3.Product=AnonTypeProduct;
            Child1 ch4=new Child4();
            ch4=result.AnonTypeChild4;
            ch4.Product=AnonTypeProduct;
            ch1list.Add(ch1);
            ch1list.Add(ch2);
            ch1list.Add(ch3);
            ch1list.Add(ch4);
        }
```

I hope this will help. However you can do this by using Include method . And I expect context to be object of ObjectContext or DBContext.